# How to run VIMEO API on php?

Tags: php, api, vimeo

**Hi Guys, im a newbie in PHP and programming. My problem is, I have tons of video on Vimeo platform. And I am trying to run my API in PHP. The following codes are the API commands. And when I executed it, I cant see any results.
And this is the API documentation. Please help me because this is my first time doing this and i have no clue what to do.**

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <?php
      require '{path_to_root_folder}/autoload.php';
      use Vimeo\Vimeo;

      $client = new Vimeo("{191e3071cfe69f8d48424621488a76b06c2bd19b}",
      "{YDxiujy1nd+s4/w9q4xRq0O1dX0OEu1xs7Fhdce5/H69HJSDWXrYvPV8Y4RHFVPUgMIGsw9fr2+QHzpHPj/x9cmva8sjRA5aBppYDAbZa9Rj/N1/rPWDDJHmgFJ2WI8Y}",
      "{c725c21e7827b252d4574be2cbe1220c}");

      $response = $client->request('/tutorial', array(), 'GET');
      print_r($response);

       ?>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's your exact question about this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's another part to this that may be missing -- have you installed the Vimeo PHP library on your server? You'll need to do so before executing that script and making a request to the `/tutorial` endpoint.

Vimeo library SDKs are listed here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries. The PHP library specifically can be found on GitHub here: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php.

Comment: hi there thank you for your reply. But I saw this syntax, I'm confuse like where is my root folder? I don't really understand this concept?  Is it the file path of my project??


require '{path_to_root_folder}/autoload.php';